# Spark-mllib retraining saved models

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to make a classification with spark-mllib, especially using RandomForestModel.

I have taken a look on this example from spark (RandomForestClassificationExample.scala), but I need a somewhat expanded approach.

I need to be able to train a model, save the model for future usage, but also to be able to load it and train further. Like, extend the dataset and train again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely understand the need to export and import a model for future usage.

Unfortunately, training "further" isn't possible with Spark nor does it make sense. Thus it's recommended to *retrain* the model with the data from use to train the first model + new data.

Your first training values/metrics don't have much sense anymore if you want to add more data (e.g features, intercept, coefficients, etc.)

I hope that this answers your question.

Comment: To add, the only thing that might make sense is to use the formerly trained model parameters as your starting point in training the model with the new/extended dataset. However, you should also run the model with a _clean slate_ state for parameters to check if you are not overfitting. Thus, I agree with eliasah that _retraining_ makes little sense.

Comment: Given that online learning is a big field - why does further training make no sense? It certainly doesn't seem out of place to at least support basic SGD whenever it's possible...?

Comment: that's true that retraining doesn't make sense but what if the training data is so huge (even many spark clusters will take days to train it) and we have to split it into batches of training data. then retrain the already fitted model on the second batch of data for example. Does it make sense in this case to tretrain the fitted model otherwise what other alternative is there ?

Comment: @EmnaJaoua Spark is made for big amounts of data.

Comment: yes that's true but my data is in the order of billions

Comment: @EmnaJaoua and you are doing what with that ? Software architecture may differ from serving one model to another. Your description is quite broad, thus I can't "suggest" a solution.

Comment: yes correct. I am using as data processing platform databricks (which is based on Spark). I am using or I want to use the huge data that I have to train a random forest classifier. this classifier is used for content recommendation. So my classifier decides whether an article category is the correct one or not. my data has 10 different categories.So in my case, I though if I can divide my training data into batches, feed the first batch to random forest classifier for training, save the model and then load it again to retrain it on the second batch of data.

Comment: @EmnaJaoua in this case, why random forest ?

Comment: actually I started many times with LightgbmClassifier but it failed since my data is huge and it's unbalanced dataset. So I moved recently to random forest since it's an ensemble classification algorithm as well and according to this article it's good for high dimensional problem. and the training actually worked for me.

Comment: https://medium.com/@aravanshad/gradient-boosting-versus-random-forest-cfa3fa8f0d80

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197498/discussion-between-eliasah-and-emna-jaoua).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to look for some reinforcement learning technique instead of Random Forest if you want to use the old model and retrain it with new data.

That I know, there's [deeplearning4j](http://deeplearning4j.org/) that implements deep reinforcement learning algorithms on top of Spark (and Hadoop).

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to save `JavaRDD[Object]`, you can do (in Java)

```
model.saveAsObjectFile()
```

Values will be writter out using Java Serialization. Then, to read your data you do:

```
JavaRDD[Object] model = jsc.objectFile(pathOfYourModel)
```

Be careful, object files are not available in Python. But you could use `saveAsPickleFile()` to write your model and `pickleFile()` to read it.